# Apache Caching disabled when client sends If-Modified-Since header

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, mod-cache

I'm trying to get Apache to cache the results from running an expensive PHP script (it accesses a third party server which has rate limiting) but it seems if the client sends an `If-Modified-Since` header the cache is bypassed.

```
CacheEnable disk /script.php
CacheLock on
CacheLockMaxAge 60
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
# prevent client explicitly requesting un-cached content
CacheIgnoreCacheControl on
CacheDetailHeader on
```

The php script sets the following headers in its response:

- `Last-Modified` set to the current time, e.g. `Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:30:20 GMT`
- `Expires` set to the current time plus 60 seconds, e.g. `Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:31:20 GMT`

If I issue the following request:

```
GET /script.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

Then the caching works correctly and the php script is only run once a minute with other requests being served from the cache.

However issuing the following request:

```
GET /script.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:30:30 GMT
```

Runs the php script every time with:

```
X-Cache-Detail: "cache miss: attempting entity save" from example.com
```

in the response.

I'm using Apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can you try setting the two headers ?

`"CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On"` and `"CacheIgnoreHeaders If-Modified-Since"`

Comment: @SreerajKarichery no change from setting those settings in mod_cache

Comment: there might be a chance to use `<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset If-Modified-Since
</FilesMatch>` or similar

Comment: @djdomi no, no change. I think I'd already tried that, I'm not sure the headers are removed before mod_cache sees them

Comment: thats why you should try to remove it :)

Comment: By thee way, i found maybe some intressting point to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847157/handling-if-modified-since-header-in-a-php-script

Answer (score 0):

##### Mod-Cache Manual from Apache.org

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html

##### Using Custom Logs to identify the problem

```
CustomLog "cached-requests.log" common env=cache-hit
CustomLog "uncached-requests.log" common env=cache-miss
CustomLog "revalidated-requests.log" common env=cache-revalidate
CustomLog "invalidated-requests.log" common env=cache-invalidate
```

##### Enable the X-Cache-Detail header

CacheDetailHeader on

##### Set to Ignore Query Cache Control Strings

```
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
CacheIgnoreQueryString on
```

##### Using a Session token like url.com/my.php?jsessionid=123 should not be cached or even seperatly

```
CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers jsessenionid
```

##### Use MINIMUM modified factor, that uncached request will be delivered 0.0 = 0% or 1.0 = 100%

```
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.99
```

##### Set Minimum time for Valid caching (Default 0)

```
CacheMinExpire 3600
```

##### Remove if-Modfied Header before it will take action

```
Header unset Last-Modified 
* Can also be used in htaccess
```

This is more to debug at first as it would not Fit in a Comment but should help to Inc raise the Caching of any Object.

Comment: `CacheDetailHeader` is already on. `CacheIgnoreCacheControl` is already on. `CacheIgnoreQueryString` is undesirable as the query string changes the returned result. `CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers` wont change anything as there is no session ID in the URL. `CacheLastModifiedFactor` and `CacheMinExpire` only apply when `Expires` isn't specified. `Header unset` doesn't seem to affect `mod_cache`'s behaviour

Comment: There's a second way but it makes it a bit more confusing, use Nginx in front of the Apache, it has more control over the caching.